# How do I require an action to happen to two elements before an event occurs in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, selector, mouseenter, mouseleave

I feel as though I am missing something simple but essentially I am trying to have a section of content drop down when the title is hovered over. Then when neither the title nor the content that was selected is touched by the mouse cursor, I would like the content to slide back up. I have tried using .add or using multiple selectors and it seems to not be working. I need the content to stay long enough for someone to select a link within it but whenever you navigate aware from the title, the content disappears.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cat1").hide()
  $("#title1").on("mouseenter",function(){
    $("#cat1").slideDown();
  });
  $("#cat1").add("#title1").on("mouseleave",function(){
    $("#cat1").slideUp();
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h4 id="title1">Getting Started</h4>
<div id="cat1">
  <ul>
    <li>Line</li>
    <li>Line</li>
    <li>Line</li>
    <li>Line</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution would be to encapsulate the related pieces.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cat1").hide();

    $(".menuItem").on("mouseenter", function() {
      $("#cat1").slideDown();
    });

    $(".menuItem").on("mouseleave", function() {
      $("#cat1").slideUp();
    });
  });

</script>
<div class="menuItem">
  <h4 id="title1">Getting Started</h4>
  <div id="cat1">
    <ul>
      <li>Line</li>
      <li>Line</li>
      <li>Line</li>
      <li>Line</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

By targeting the wrapped element you insure that the mouseleave event will not trigger when leaving the title to go to the contents.  Only when it leaves the shared area.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of `.add("#title1")` and I think you get what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cat1").hide()
$("#title1").on("mouseenter",function(){
$("#cat1").slideDown();
});
$("#cat1").on("mouseleave",function(){
$("#cat1").slideUp();
});
 }); 
</script>
<h4 id="title1">Getting Started</h4>
<div id="cat1">
<ul>
    <li>Line</li>
    <li>Line</li>
    <li>Line</li>
    <li>Line</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/jonmrich/1d6d7k9x/1/

Comment: potential issue with this as implemented is that you have to enter and leave the div for it to collapse again, I can't just roll across the h tag and have it disappear if that is not what I wanted to see.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions occur to me, though I haven't tried either one.

First, put a wrapper around your h and div, then attach your events to the wrapper.

```
<div id="menu1">  <-- Events go here
<h4 id="title1">Getting Started</h4>
<div id="cat1">
<ul>
    <li>Line</li>
    <li>Line</li>
    <li>Line</li>
    <li>Line</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

The other option would be to style your cat div such that it overlays the heading, and only attach the mouse leave to the div, not the heading.